# Accessing elements of OpenCV Mat CV_16UC1

Tags: c++, opencv

i tried with the following line code:

```
image.at<char>(row, column);
image.at<uchar>(row, column);
image.at<unsigned char>(row, column);
image.at<double>(row, column);
```

what is wrong?

after that, i need to convert this value to a float. A casting is enough?

Comment: Tell us what results you're getting vs. what results you expect.  Is it failing to compile?

Comment: I don't have compiling error. it crashes, showing me that:                 First-chance exception at 0x773c2eec in RobotClient.DebugVC10.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0078d11c..

Answer (score 9):

CV_16UC1 has unsigned short as an underlying type, so you probably need

```
unsigned short val = image.at<unsigned short>(row, column);
```

And yes, you can simply static cast that to a float afterwards:

```
float fval = static_cast<float>(val);
```

Comment: hi, now it works. but it works if i run the code using breakpoints, if i don't use them, the program crashes. maybe it's because  the image,at function in within a for cycle

Comment: You're probably running into a different problem at this point, most likely some kind of timing bug.

Comment: hi! i solved the other problem, i can concentrate on the conversion i need! There is no building error, but the conversion is always zero. I'm sure the cv::Mat image is different than zero because i plot it using OpenGL libraries. what could the problem be?

Comment: @maury88ct I would post a new question explaining the new problem and what you've done in OpenGL to verify that the matrix looks reasonable.

Comment: I prefer include `stdint.h` and use `uint16_t` just to be explicit.